# Share Android internet from proxy Server app via hotspot or usb tethering

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I have a proxy Server android app that lets you modify outgoing http requests
that app Called  "Simple Server Android"

With it I Managed to get a free internet from my Carrier (Hacked connection)
By adding proxy and port to it

every thing is Work just fine on my android , But I Want to share this connection to my computer with this settings

Comment: On pc type on search box configure proxyserver then tap lan settings and voila configure your own proxy

Answer (score 0):

A stock android feature is that you can use your device as a portable hotspot. On that device, go settings → more (in the wireless an. Networks chunk) → tethering and portable hotspot, in which you'll see two options: Portable WiFi hotspot(is a checkbox) and setup WiFi hotspot.

Choose set-up, and give it the name and password of your choice. Then save, turn it on (Mobile data must be on, just as WiFi connection need to be off) and connect your computer to it as you would to any wireless network(assuming you are on Windows, internet icon in bottom right) click it then your hot-spot, put in the password and you are done!

Comment: dude that didn't work for me I already did it before i even ask this question 

When I use a hotspot my android share only a regular connection without a proxy server setting  without this setting I can't open any thing in my computer 



So I need Mobile data to make  it through (proxy server app) before I use  it in my computer I hope I make it Clear

Comment: Hmmm. Look below. Also can you send me your data for this proxy? Send it to moveslikebill@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to set proxy in Wi-Fi settings on your PC too. The reason is that hotspot network cannot be configured to use proxy without modifying NAT rules and/or kernel routing table at OSI layer 2/3. Proxy is used on per-connection basis by apps themselves, it's not enforced system-wide. For details see [Why proxy set on Android does not work when used as hotspot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217848/218526)